# Empty set is subset or element of power set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For a set $A$, the power set of A is denoted by $2^A$. If $A$= {5,{6},{7}}, which of the following options are TRUE?

I) ϕ ∈ $2^A$

II) ϕ ⊆ $2^A$

III) {5,{6}} ∈ $2^A$

IV) {5,{6}} ⊆ $2^A$

Answer:

1) I and III

2) II and III

3) I, II and III

4) I, II and IV

It is given in the text that correct answer is option 3) I, II and III.

> My question: Is the null set an element (I) and a subset (II) of the powerset? If so, how?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of any set, and it is an element of any power set

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) is a subset of any set, and it is an element of any power set.

$O\subseteq P$ means $x\in O\implies x\in P$, which is a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) when $O$ is the empty set.

Furthermore, if $O\subseteq A$, then $O\in 2^A,$ by definition of the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).